# request don't have parameters in doPost servlet

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

I have a problem in a servlet where I do a POST request using a form submit but, in the servlet side, displays there isn't any parameter to work with. I don't know what could be causing this problem or how to fix it.

This is my form submit:

```
<table>
    <form name="eliAlumno" id="eliAlumno" method="POST" action="DelAlumno">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="radio" name="radioGroup" class="radioButtonEli" value="0"></input></td>
        <td>any name</td>
        <td>any last name</td>
        <td>any string</td>
        <td>any number</td>
        <td>true or false</td>
        <td><input type="submit" id="0" value="Eliminar"></input></td>
    </tr>
    </form>
</table>
```

This is my JavaScript

```
$("#eliAlumno").submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[1].style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(del, 3000);

    function del() {
        document.getElementsByClassName("loader")[1].style.display = "none";
        $.ajax({
            url: "DelAlumno",
            type: "POST",
            data: $("#eliAlumno").serialize()
        })
                .done(function (json) {
                    bootbox.alert({
                        size: "small",
                        title: "Exito",
                        message: "El alumno ha sido eliminado adecuadamente."
                    });
                })
                .fail(function (xhr, status, errorThrown) {
                    bootbox.alert({
                        size: "large",
                        title: "Error",
                        message: "El alumno no se eliminó adecuadamente\n\
información del error: <br>" + errorThrown
                    });
                });
    }
});
```

And this is my servlet `doPost` method

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    Gson g = new Gson();
    ProcessDataDel pdd = new ProcessDataDel();
    int id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("radioGroup"));
    pdd.deleteAlu(id, g);
    response.sendRedirect("consulta.jsp");
}
```

But the `HttpServletRequest` object doesn't have any parameter when I'm debbuging.

Comment: Is there at least one button selected when you submit?  If no buttons are selected then there will be no parameter submitted.

Comment: Yes, one button is selected when I do the submit

Comment: I'd start by using the tools in the browser - either the developer tools in Chrome or Firebug in Firefox.  This will help you see what is being sent by the browser.  It will require you to dig into a bit as the post will likely be URL encoded but you can verify first that the HTML/JavaScript side is sending what you expect.

Comment: When I submit to the servlet I can see that the request in the browser size in fact is sending the parameter "radioGroup" with a value of "2"

Answer (score 0):

I thing you are mixing what is an controller and a servlet.
What you are trying to do is a call to an Action not a servlet doPost.

Comment: No, the poster is not using Struts.

Answer (score 0):

I've come with an answer of my own question.

for some reazon it IS really important the order of AJAX method when sending data.

Instead of:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "DelAlumno",
    type: "POST",
    data: $("#eliAlumno").serialize()
})
```

It must be:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "DelAlumno",
    data: $("#eliAlumno").serialize(),
    type: "POST"
})
```

I suspect that if type is before that data, the servlet enter the method before reading the parameters